# Eror Cannot declare class App\Models\AdminController, because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgFVj.png)
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmcXF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPWOi.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM7La.png)
Hello, I have such a problem, can you help me, I looked for similar examples in the forum, but I could not solve the problem.

Hello, I have such a problem, can you help me, I looked for similar examples in the forum, but I could not solve the problem.

version laravel 10x

Comment: google found laracasts post
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cannot-declare-class-because-the-name-is-already-in-use-2

to me, the double namespace is quite suspicious, maybe I just never seen it though

Comment: looking at your screenshots again, you definitely want the controllers namespace, not models

Answer (score 0):

There are things wrong in the AdminController.php. It should be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
//...
```